# requesting data from a url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I m trying to retrieve images and videos from a server. m using the following code..

```
- (void)sendBodyRequestWithTopLeftX:(NSNumber *)tx 
                       topLeftY:(NSNumber *)ty 
                   bottomRightX:(NSNumber *)bx
                   bottomRightY:(NSNumber *)by 
                       dateFrom:(NSDate *)dateFrom 
                         dateTo:(NSDate *)dateTo{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server/searchMedia?topLeftX=<float>&topLeftY=<float>&bottomRightX=<float>&bottomRightY=<float>&dateFrom=<date>&dateTo=<date>"];
_request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self sendRequest];
[_request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[_request setPostValue:tx forKey:@"topLeftX"];
[_request setPostValue:ty forKey:@"topLeftY"];
[_request setPostValue:bx forKey:@"bottomRightX"];
[_request setPostValue:by forKey:@"bottomRightY"];
[_request setPostValue:dateFrom forKey:@"dateFrom"];
[_request setPostValue:dateTo forKey:@"dateTo"];
[_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[_request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed)];
[_request startAsynchronous];
```

But i m not getting any response inside my `requestFinished function`. Have tried a lot of things but still not. Any one can help me out here. 
And please one more thing the value at server side is in `float` but when i change my `NSNumber` into floats it gives me an error of incompatible types. Any clue.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're setting the request's delegate; it won't know what object to notify upon completion/failure otherwise! Add this before your call to `startSynchronous`:

```
// Replace self with the object that implements requestFailed/Finished:.
[_request setDelegate:self];
```

Also, if you're using POST, why are you using a query string? It's unnecessary.

If you have any more trouble with the `ASIHTTPRequest` library, I suggest you read over the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). As for your `NSNumber` problem, we'll need more information (ideally code).

Comment: basically its like a custom class. so on completion of request i m calling requestFinished [_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];

Comment: but that selector is never been called. just wanna ask one more thing. do i have to hit the full url or i can just hit it till 
http://server/searchMedia

Comment: and sorry forgot to mention i m aso setting the delegate in the init method where i m initializing _request